# Replace string with foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have old large table `logs` with columns `type`, `message` and others. Column `type` - varchar

**LOGS**

| type | message |
| --- | --- |
| alert | Send mail notify |
| shop | Sell product1 |
| alert | Send push notify |
| forum | New user |
| shop | F*cked up on shop_module |
| shop | Sell product2 |

How can I make this table look like this?

**LOGS**

| type | message |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Send mail notify |
| 2 | Sell product1 |
| 1 | Send push notify |
| 3 | New user |
| 2 | F*cked up on shop_module |
| 2 | Sell product2 |

**LOGS_TYPE**

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | alert |
| 2 | shop |
| 3 | forum |

I only know how to do this using a PHP script. But can I only use MySQL?

*MYSQL 8.0.30-22*

**UPDATE**

I don't have a `logs_type` table yet and I want to create one based on the `logs` and then return a foreign key there. Can I do this in one request?

Comment: easiest way to create new table. insert data from query then delete table Logs and rename new table to "LOGS"

Comment: Recommendation: add numeric column, fill it with according values, then drop old column and rename new one. This is longer, but more safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your own response,when you have created that intermediate table (logs_type),
and you need to search for the data, you can link both tables with INNER JOIN, something like:

```
SELECT lt.type AS type ,l.message AS message 
FROM LOGS AS l 
  INNER JOIN 
LOGS_TYPE AS lt
  ON l.type = lt.id
```

I don't know if that solves your problem, hope it helps!

And if you want to overwrite your actual logs tables, i would try something like:

```
UPDATE LOGS SET type=1 WHERE type = 'alert';
UPDATE LOGS SET type=2 WHERE type = 'shop';
UPDATE LOGS SET type=3 WHERE type = 'forum';
```

And then you will overwrite that column with the new values corresponding to that LOGS_TYPE table you have just created.

Comment: Much better option the SelVazi response

Comment: `SET type = FIND_IN_SET('alert,shop,forum')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows :

```
UPDATE `LOGS` l
INNER JOIN LOGS_TYPE t ON t.type = l.type
SET l.type = t.id
```

It is preferable then to change data type of column `type` to TINYINT :

```
ALTER TABLE `LOGS` MODIFY type TINYINT;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WbPCI9QH)

Answer (score 0):

How to create the `logs_type` table and populate it in one step:

```
CREATE TABLE logs_type (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  type VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  KEY(type)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 0, type FROM logs;
```

(This assumes you do *not* set the `NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO` sql mode.)

Populate the `logs` data:

```
ALTER TABLE logs ADD COLUMN type_id INT;

UPDATE logs JOIN logs_type USING (type)
SET logs.type_id = logs_type.id;
```

Confirm the values are what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM logs JOIN logs_type ON logs.type_id = logs_type.id
WHERE NOT logs.type <=> logs_type.type;
```

This should return an empty set, because the `type` values should match in every joined row.

When you are satisfied the update was correct, then drop the redundant column (it's a good idea to make a backup first):

```
ALTER TABLE logs DROP COLUMN type;
```